# Footer Blocking Website Content

Tags: html

**Description:**

I'm having an issue with my website's footer blocking content on mobile browsers (and on longer pages on desktops).

I've seen threads about this before, but these focus on hiding the footer until the user scrolls all the way down. I want to have the footer "float" below the content, but have it go below the content when the user scrolls all the way down the page. I also need this to allow clicking on items right above the footer. On my site, you can't click on a button, even if it's a few lines above the footer - which needs to also be fixed.

**Examples:**

You can view an example of this issue at my own site: http://mbt.aeio.io/twitter.php

Note that when you scroll all the way down, it is impossible to click "Load More Tweets", even on desktops, where the button is clearly visible.

I cannot find an example of what I'm trying to accomplish; that's why I'm posting about this -- and not just copying someone else's code.

**Code:**

This is my code for ARRANGING the footer:

```
<head>
      <style type ="text/css" >
         .footer{
           position: fixed;
           text-align: center;
           bottom: 0px;
           width: 100%;
         }
      </style>
</head>
```

This is my ACTUAL code for the footer:

```
<div class="footer">
         <div class="content">
            <div class="container" style="
               /* display: inline-block; */
               ">
               <div class="well animated slideInUp" style="
                  display: inline-block;
                  ">
                  <center>Developed with <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> by mario_bros_tech, Arkagaen, and <a href="credits.php">Others</a> | Copyright &copy; 2015-2017 | All Rights Reserved</center>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

I know this is super-janky and that I shouldn't be using containers to make a footer, so if you have any suggestions for improving/cleaning up the code too, that would also be appreciated.

And if you need to look at the CSS for whatever reason, it is using Bootstrap and can be found here: http://mbt.aeio.io/assets/css/

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing (and the right thing) to do is to give some bottom padding to body. Giving the following code:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}
```

We get this:

[image: preview]

Comment: Rest of the site? Are you using inline styling. If so I advice you style in a separate CSS file for a less expensive management and future update.

Comment: Thank you! Changes have been pushed to that page, I will apply it to the rest of the site later today.

The only issue is that on mobile, it doesn't show the seperation; it only shows a white section... is there any way to fix that?
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/t6Qa3

Comment: @mario_bros_tech It's not a good idea to unapprove the answer. You can ask for clarification. So, for you, try wrapping it inside a `@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) { body { padding-bottom: 75px; } }`.

Comment: @OkeTega I am not sure what you mean by "Rest of the site?" and this is clearly not inline styles.

Comment: @OkeTega I'm terrible with CSS; can you provide an example? My friend did all of the styling for the site...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Where should I put the code for the mobile padding? I'm obviously putting it in the wrong place, if you look at the inspector...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Also, on the desktop, you can't click the "Embed" and "View on Twitter" buttons...

Comment: @mario_bros_tech Regarding the mobile styles, please use `@media screen and (max-width: 1024) { /* mobile styles here */ }`. Also refer https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for more info.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks, I fixed it by reducing the padding.

Comment: Write your styling in a .css file and use the `<link>` tag to link in your `html`.